# Como criar uma função para validar horário em PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando validar um campo de horário em PHP, e com a ajuda [deste tópico](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/425373-resolvido%C2%A0validar-horas/) num site externo cheguei a este script:

```
function validaHoras($campo){
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/', $campo)) {
        $horas = substr($campo, 0, 2);
        $minutos = substr($campo, 3, 2);
        if (($horas > "23") OR ($minutos > "59")) {
            $campo = false;
        }
    }
}
```

O `input` deve receber o campo no formato '00:00', mas não tem validação em JS, e o usuário pode entrar com um horário inválido.

Então o que quero é mudar o valor da variável para `false` quando vier com um horário errado (tipo 99:99), mas não está funcionando. Testando o script abaixo com o `input` 99:99, o valor da variável não é alterado...

```
function validaHoras($campo){
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/', $campo)) {
        $horas = substr($campo, 0, 2);
        $minutos = substr($campo, 3, 2);
        if (($horas > "23") OR ($minutos > "59")) {
            $campo = false;
        }
    }
}

// SEGUNDA

$val1 = isset($_POST["Tsegs"]) && !empty($_POST["Tsegs"]) ? $_POST["Tsegs"] : false;

validaHoras($val1);
echo $val1;

//saida: 99:99
//saida desejada: false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há um equivoco na chamada da função validaHoras, ela está passando o parametro mas não retorna retorna nada após a execução. A variavel que você imprime é a mesma que você passsa como parametro (por valor), ela não vai sofrer alteração. Tente assim:

```
<?php

function validaHoras($campo){
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/', $campo)) {
        $horas = substr($campo, 0, 2);
        $minutos = substr($campo, 3, 2);
        if (($horas > "23") OR ($minutos > "59")) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// SEGUNDA
$val1 = isset($_POST["Tsegs"]) && !empty($_POST["Tsegs"]) ? $_POST["Tsegs"] : false;

if(validaHoras($val1) === true){
    echo 'hora valida ' . $val1;
}else {
    echo 'hora invalida ' . $val1;
}
```

Comment: $horas > "23" ?? Por que não converte o retorno da regex pra inteiro e compara? Comparação de maior com string é estranho , ainda mais dando margem para falácias com php..

Comment: @Marlysson se fosse só por string, "1A:2X" daria verdadeiro nesse caso, mas como filtrou na RegEx antes, ainda passa, acho. Dá para fazer com string de maneira muito eficiente ([postei uma alternativa aqui mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/481609/70)) mas tem que testar byte a byte. A vantagem é que fazemos cada teste uma vez só, dispensando totalmente a necessidade da RegEx e qualquer tipo de conversão numérica ou modificação de string.

Answer (score 10):

É possível validar o formato e o contéudo somente com expressões regulares caso deseje. `^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])`.

`^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])` **=>** O primeiro grupo captura a hora no formato (00-23) ele define três tipos 'categorias' a primeira indentifica valores de 00 a 09, o segundo de 10 a 19 e o último de 20 até 23.

`([0-5][0-9])` **=>** O segundo grupo cobre os minutos que tem um lógica um pouco diferente das horas. Captura um dígito que pode estar entre zero e cinco e outro que pode estar entre zero e nove, o que cobre 00 a 59

```
function validaHoras($campo){
    return preg_match('/^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/', $campo) ? $campo : false;
}


$arr = array('00:00', '19:59', '20:34', '24:33', '28:64', '07:59', '000:30', '30:50');

foreach($arr as $item) var_dump(validaHoras($item)) .'<br>';
```

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/iM8J5M)

Comment: Muito bom! Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção com sanitização.

A rotina sanitiza a entrada do usuário, removendo tudo que não for número, porém, preserva o caracter `:`.

Converte também caracteres numéricos full-width (zenkaku) e aceita hora e minuto com 1 dígito. Exemplo: 1:10, 1:6 (01:10, 01:06)

A sanitização torna a validação mais amigável ao usuário.

```
function numbers_only($str, $exception = '')
{
    return preg_replace('#[^0-9'.$exception.']#', '', mb_convert_kana($str, 'n'));
}

function valid_hour($n)
{
    $n = str_replace('：', ':', $n);
    $n = numbers_only($n, ':');

    $arr = explode(':', $n);
    if (count($arr) == 2) {
        $h = intval($arr[0]);
        $m = intval($arr[1]);
        if ($h <= 23 && $h >= 0 && $m <= 59 && $m >= 0) {
            return str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$str[0] = '0000'; // (inválido pois é necessário o separador : )
$str[1] = '００：０９'; // caracteres zenkaku (válido)
$str[2] = '00:00'; // (válido)
$str[3] = '0:06'; // (válido)
$str[4] = '0:0'; // (válido)
$str[5] = '00:0'; // (válido)
$str[6] = '01:60'; // (inválido pois os minutos ultrapassaram o limite)
$str[7] = '01:6.'; // (válido, pois o ponto no final é removido na sanitização)

/*
Quando for inválido, retorna booleano false.
Quando for válido, retorna a string do usuário sanitizada e formatada como hh:mm, mesmo que o usuário insira apenas 1 dígito para hora ou minuto.
*/

var_dump(valid_hour($str[7]));
```

Comment: Muito bom Daniel, e ainda soluciona vários problemas recorrentes de informação de horários inválidos... excelente mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Segue um "protótipo" bem sucinto, usando o mais básico do básico, que é validação com `if`.

(sem precisar de RegEx, conversões ou mesmo de operações modificando string)

```
function pareceHora($str)
{
   return strlen($str) == 5
          && $str[2] == ':'
          && $str[0] >= '0' && $str[0] <= '2'
          && $str[1] >= '0' && $str[1] <= ($str[0]=='2'?'3':'9')
          && $str[3] >= '0' && $str[3] <= '5'
          && $str[4] >= '0' && $str[4] <= '9';
}
```

Veja funcionando: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/IEiv0y)

- A sintaxe `$string[n]` acessa o byte de numero `n` da *string* diretamente
- na 3ª linha  nos certificamos do tamanho ser 5 caracteres
- na 4ª de ter `:` no meio
- na 5ª e 6ª linhas verificamos a hora entre 00 e 23, usando comparação ASCII. É feito um dígito por vez para que uma string '1A' não seja considerada válida (se testássemos '00' a '23' daria estes efeitos colaterais)
- na 7ª e 8ª linhas é a mesma coisa, só que para os minutos.

Desta forma, validamos os 5 caracteres da string completamente (faixa e forma) com operações básicas e eficientes.

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver considerando horas apenas de `00:00` e `23:59`, você pode utilizar simplesmente o método `DateTime::createFromFormat` ou a função, que é o apelido para esta primeira, `date_create_from_format`

Assim:

```
date_create_from_format('!H:i', $valor);
```

Se retornar `DateTime`, é um valor válido. Se retornar `false`, é inválido.

Porém temos um problema aqui. Essa função aceita valores como `24:99` como hora válida, convertendo seus valores para horas corretas quando passados. No caso de `24:99`, seria convertido para `1970-01-02 01:39:00`.

Para contornar isso, poderíamos usar a função que cria a data a partir do formato e depois, usando o mesmo formato para a saída, comparar com o valor de entrada.

Veja:

```php
function validar_hora($hora) 
{
   $formato = 'H:i';

   $data = date_create_from_format('!'. $formato, $hora);

   return $data && $data->format($formato) === $hora;
}


validar_hora('23:55'); // true
validar_hora('24:00'); // false
```

Isso ocorre porque:

Ao aplicar `'H:i'` em `'24:00'` é convertido para `'1970-01-02 00:00:00'`, que é convertido para `00:00` ao chamar `'H:i'` para formatá-lo.

No caso de `'23:55'`, é convertido para `'1970-01-01 23:55:00'`, que é convertido para `'23:55'` ao chamar `format`.

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/gr0oiL).

Essa é uma solução alternativa se não quiser utilizar REGEX.

> **Nota:**: O `!`, conforme a documentação, redefine todos os campos para a "época" Unix (1970-01-01)

## Atualização

Ainda pensando numa solução que gaste menos linhas do que a primeira que apresentei, apliquei os "mesmos fundamentos" às funções `date` e `strtotime`. A função `strtotime` converte uma `string` para timestamp. Já a função `date` retorna a data formatada a partir do `timestamp`, quando passado o segundo parâmetro.

Podemos fazer dessa forma:

```
function validar_hora($hora)
{
    return date('H:i', strtotime($hora)) == $hora;
}
```

https://ideone.com/4dWLzv